# Changing MAC address on the Fly on old kernel 2.6.x

Tags: kernel, mac-address, linux-kernel

I'm doing some research on old kernels and running the following on 2.6.7 or 2.6.8 gives a resource busy error. But on 2.6.28 the command works as expected. How would I determine which kernel allowed this command to change the mac address on the fly? ip link set dev  addr

You can see some screenshots below. Thank you!
[image]
<sub>(source: [linuxquestions.org](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/attachment.php?attachmentid=3340&d=1271355586))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [linuxquestions.org](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/attachment.php?attachmentid=3341&d=1271355596))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [linuxquestions.org](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/attachment.php?attachmentid=3342&d=1271355610))</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a driver related issue.  Once we received new drivers from the manufacture the task worked as its supposed to be.